# Do large companies pay for shills?

Tags: consumer-products, commerce

On many forums and sites facilitating discussion, whenever the topic of consumerism is raised (eg. Android over iOS), there is a  common accusation that one of the parties is a [shill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shill) - someone paid to present an argument in favour of a corporation, while posing as a customer.

So large corporations such as Apple, Microsoft, Monsanto, and others actually use these methods?

Comment: This question seems too broad, it is likely that at least one, but not all large companies have used shills at least once during their existence.

Comment: Yep, this can't be disproved: voting to close.

Comment: It is unquestionable that *some* large companies pay people to make pasts that benefit them on the internet without revealing that they are doing so on behalf of the company.